# How to handle default system generated pop ups for iOS native mobile application automation?

Tags: ios

I am doing ioS Mobile automation testing for Native application.

I am getting an system generated location alert "... would like to use your Current Location"while opening the application in simulator . I am not able to handle this with Selenium as i am not able to capture this alert  box using Inspector .

Is there any way to handle this with the help of capabilities (while setting the capabilities ) .

I have also tried setting the below capabilities but this is not working :
Capability-type.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_ALERTS, true)
"autoAcceptAlert`

I am using Java + Appium + Web Driver +Sikuli.

Please help on this .

Comment: please explain in detail

Comment: You can turn off Location Services if you don’t want to use this feature. That way app won't ask users permission.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to set it in [desired capabilities](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md)
`capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);`

Comment: HI Tiny ,I tried using "autoAcceptAlerts" but this is not working .Is there any other capability type through which we can handle this .Please help!

Comment: set `locationServicesAuthorized`

Comment: I tried using locationServicesAuthorized :true but in this case I am not able to initialize the driver object.The driver object is null.Is there any other way to use locationServicesAuthorized .

Answer (score 0):

I came across this nasty issue once. I'm afraid to say that after lots of effort I found no way to solve this issue except that the developers of the iOS application actually have to delay that popup to show up a few seconds after the app launches instead of right away. Then only `autoAcceptAlerts` works. Even `autoAcceptAlerts` didn't work for me if the popup showed right on launch.

Answer (score 0):

System generated pop up should be having xpaths etc that can be found out using Appium Inspector.

Just click on the necessary button on that pop up by providing xpath to that button to make it close.

Comment: I am having the same problem as the original poster of this question. The problem is that when the app is launched via Inspector, it will not show in the inspector/recorder until the alert ("Please allow notifications" has been manually accepted.) Setting the capability (autoAcceptAlert does not work either for these System or OS level notifications)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue today with selecting an alert allowing push notifications. I solved this by running the app from Appium.app and using the inspector to access the element.(I was previously launching it using appium ruby console).

To run from appium.app click the Apple radio button to bring up a settings page. Here set the .app file to install and the device to run on. Launch the Node server and press the inspector button. The Java code that was generated was as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("OK")).click();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This works for me when I set the combination of `Thread.sleep` in the test beginning and `autoAcceptAlerts` desired capability `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your desired capabilities dictionary.

```
'waitForAppScript': '$.delay(5000); true',
'autoAcceptAlerts': True
```